# Get substring then replace

Tags: javascript

I want to get a portion of a string via `.substring(indexStart, indexEnd)` then replace the same portion in the original string.

```
var portion = "my new house".substring(3, 6),
    portion = "old";

// what's next?
```

Comment: `.replace("partofstring", "newvalue")`

Comment: the code you provided does not make any sense at all. So the question might not be, what is next, but where to start. JAvscripts replace method should be a good starting point for you: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I only want to replace the portion between the characters indexStart and indexEnd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the surrounding substrings and concatenate:

```
var str = "my new house";
str = str.slice(0, 3) + "old" + str.slice(6);
console.log(str); // "my old house"
```

Of course, this is assuming you want to replace parts of the string marked off by certain indeces. If you just want to replace a word, you would use:

```
str = str.replace(/new/g, 'old');
```

(Omit the `g`lobal flag to only replace the first occurrence.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call 'replace' on the original string to find the substring you gathered and replace it with the new desired string.

```
var oldString = "my new house my new house";
var subStr = oldString.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
var newValue = "old";
var newString = oldString.replace(subStr, newValue);
```

Comment: This breaks for ex. `"newnew house"` (which would result in `"oldnew house"` instead of `"newold house"`).

Comment: Also, what if the portion was duplicated in string like "my new house my new house"? I would just like to replace the characters between indexStart and indexEnd